# If $\overline A$ is compact, then $\overline A=\overline A^w$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff topological vector space such that $X'$,it topological dual separate points of $X$, and $A\subset X$. I want to know if the following sytatement is true or not?

If $\overline A$ is compact, then $\overline{A}=\overline{A}^w$, where $w$ denotes the weak closure.

My attemp: Since $$A\subset \overline{A}\subset \overline A^w,$$

taking weak closure from sides of the above inclusions, we have

$$\overline{A}^w\subset \overline{\overline{A}}^w\subset \overline{A}^w$$
which gives $\overline{\overline{A}}^w=\overline{A}^w$. From compactness of $\overline{A}$, we know it is weakly compact, and hence weakly closed, so $\overline{\overline{A}}^w=\overline{A}$.

Comment: Your argument is correct. There's not much to add.